# Import problems

Tags: python, import, path, init

On the following path:

```
main
    system.py
    |-----pid
             init.py
             pid.py
             tunning_methods.py
```

pid.py has the following relevant import lines:

```
import tunning_methods
```

tunning_methods.py does not import any other file as it does not need it.
init.py is empty, and system.py has the following import lines:

```
import pid.tunning_methods
import pid.pid
```

every file has a function to test it on the format:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     testfunc()
```

now when i try to run pid.py it runs just fine, however when i try to run system.py it raises an error saying the is no such module named tunning_methods.py on the pid.py file. I was able to solve that by importing "import pid.tunning_methods" on the pid.py it was like on the system vision of import path, instead of the pid, however the pid now does not run, more than that im having a lot of trouble with imports, this is just a piece of application that goes in to a much bigger one, its possible to do this for every import, however i want an easier solution, any ideas ?

tried to do the imports on the description and it did not work as i was intending.

Comment: Try a relative import: `from . import tunning_methods`.

Comment: And it should be `__init__.py`, not `init.py`

Answer (score 0):

for anyone having the same problem the suggestion that Michael gave worked, a relative import `from . import tunning_methods`.